# Getting an Exception Error

Tags: java, numberformatexception

Ok, so I'm working on a method that is supposed to combine a set of binary numbers. For some reason I'm getting an exception on it. The method works when the numberOfBits is 4, but it gives an error when I move up to 7. I'm not exactly sure why it's doing this and nothing so far has fixed it. Any thoughts? Error is noted in code below. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "111001101100111"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:461)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:554)
at MP1.combine(MP1.java:96)
at MP1.shiftRight(MP1.java:76)
at MP1.main(MP1.java:131)

public Integer combine(Register register, int numberOfBits) {
    String C1 = Integer.toBinaryString(register.C);
    String A1 = Integer.toBinaryString(register.A);
    String Q1 = Integer.toBinaryString(register.Q);

    C1 = String.format("%1s", C1).replace(' ', '0');
    A1 = String.format("%" + numberOfBits + "s", A1).replace(' ', '0');
    Q1 = String.format("%" + numberOfBits + "s", Q1).replace(' ', '0');

    String comboS = C1 + A1 + Q1;

    //Says error is here (below)
    Integer comboI = Integer.valueOf(comboS); 

    return comboI;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max value of Integer is `2147483647`, and obviously `111001101100111` is much bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

`Integer.valueOf(comboS)` calls `Integer.parseInt(str)` eventually. That's why you received a `NumberFormatException`.

If your want to parse `111001101100111` in binary rather than decimalism. `Integer.parseInt(comboS, 2)` will work.

Or use `BigInteger` instead, which has no upper limit.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer and way to get around it. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Print out your comboS string before trying to get the `valueOf` it, and you will see the strange number you have.

I am guessing that it does not fit into an Integer.

Comment: Ah...that makes sense. At 7 bits, the 15 bit integer would be much too big. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I need the preceding zeros for the binary codes when I combine them. For example, if I input 2 at 4 bits and convert it to a binary string, I only get "10" but I need "0010". Doing the format and replace gives me the extra zeros I need.

Comment: I understand the `format`, but not the `replace`.  Why would there be blanks in your string?

Comment: They're actually spaces, not blanks. The format `"%" + numberOfBits + "s"` gives me a String of `numberOfBits` spaces (the `"s"` being space) and then the `replace` replaces the spaces with zeros, because where all the spaces are I will need zeros.